# using a string as an array name

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to dynamically get the name of the correct array, then display the contents of that array. Not sure how to do this:

html:

```
<div class="grid" id="arrSemmes">
      <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="img/2019/s1-thumb.jpg" /></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="img/2019/s2-thumb.jpg" /></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="img/2019/s3-thumb.jpg" /></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="img/2019/s4-thumb.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
    var thisIndex;
    var arrSemmes = [
        ["2019/s1.jpg", "caption1"],
        ["2019/s2.jpg", "caption2"],
        ["2019/s3.jpg", "caption3"],
        ["2019/s4.jpg", "caption4"],
    ];

$('.grid-item img').on('click', function() {
        var thisArray = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id'); //returns a string: arrSemmes
        thisIndex = $(this).attr('src');
        thisIndex = thisIndex.replace('-thumb.jpg','');
        thisIndex = thisIndex.replace('img/2019/s','');
        thisIndex = thisIndex--; //must be one less for the array key
        alert(thisArray[thisIndex][0]); //thinks I want a letter in the string "thisArray"
    });
```

Comment: `thisIndex` is a String, so `thisIndex--` doesn't make sense.  You can't subtract 1 from a string.

Comment: *"...get the name of the correct array"*  The name of what array?

Comment: @zer00ne: the array called arrSemmes, which is the id of the grid and is the variable name for a multi-dimensional array in my code.

Comment: *"/thinks I want a letter in the string "thisArray""* A string can be an array if you index it it will treat each character as an array element.

Comment: @zer00ne: My question is, how do I get the code to treat thisArray as an array and not a string?

Comment: The last line is an array of single characters that's why you got a letter.

Comment: @LauraNMS Please post an example of the result you want and a better explination than just an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify your logic.  Use data attributes and remove the positional based logic.

From your comment, I've also included logic for the previous and next buttons, using a class to identify which image is the current one, and adjusting accordingly.

```js
var $images = $('.grid-item img').on('click', function() {
  var $img = $(this);
  console.log($img.data('src'), $img.data('caption'));
  
  $images.removeClass('current');
  $img.addClass('current');
});

function adjustCurrentImage ( adjustment ) {
  var currentImageIndex = $images.index($images.filter('.current'));
  var nextImageIndex = currentImageIndex + adjustment;
  
  if (-1 < nextImageIndex && nextImageIndex < $images.length) {
    $images.removeClass('current');
    $images.eq(nextImageIndex).addClass('current');
    console.log($images.eq(nextImageIndex).data('src'), $images.eq(nextImageIndex).data('caption'));
  }
}

$('#prev').on('click', function(){ adjustCurrentImage(-1); });
$('#next').on('click', function(){ adjustCurrentImage(1); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid" id="arrSemmes">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="img/2019/s1-thumb.jpg" data-src="2019/s1.jpg" data-caption="caption1" /></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="img/2019/s2-thumb.jpg" data-src="2019/s2.jpg" data-caption="caption2" /></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="img/2019/s3-thumb.jpg" data-src="2019/s3.jpg" data-caption="caption3" /></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="img/2019/s4-thumb.jpg" data-src="2019/s4.jpg" data-caption="caption4" /></div>
</div>
<button id="prev">Previous Image</button>
<button id="next">Next Image</button>
```

Comment: I need the array because I will be allowing the user to click arrows to go forward and backward through the images in a popup window.

Comment: @LauraNMS edited the answer to show that the next and previous logic can be done without the array as well.

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as correct, but it will mean I'll have to rename all the images in my other arrays.